# How to disallow UILocalNotifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to disable local notifications within an app - similar to what a user would do in the Settings app

Here is what I tried:

```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUser NotificationSettings(forTypes: .None, categories: nil))
```

That did not work. Is there another way?

Cheers

**EDIT**

The customer want's such a switch in the App. It should disable/enable local notifications. If the switch is off the App will not create any local notifications. However, there is an inconsistency: the switch in the App is off, the switch in the Settings App is still on. That may be confusing. And again - it's the kings wish to have such a switch - so I have to obey.

Comment: Just don't post any notifications?  You can't change the permissions programmatically once the user has answered the initial request.

Comment: But local notifications will only be created if you create any. What have you done else?

Comment: "The customer wants" is irrelevant if it isn't possible to do what they want.

Comment: @Fogmeister: are u sure that it is not possible?

Comment: Just register for the permissions, and have a boolean that is controlled by some UI interface in your application.  If the boolean is false then do not schedule any remote notifications or alert the user of any remote.

Comment: @abnormi yes. That's why I said it. If you could change app permissions in the settings like this there would be nothing stopping you turning them on too. If you want a way to turn off notifications in the app then just respond to that by deleting notifications and not creating any more. You cannot change the settings app though.

Comment: @Fogmeister: Well.. there is a way to turn local notifications on, i.e: 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))

I was just wondering if there is way to revers that. If not - it is OK with me :)

Comment: @abnormi no, you are not turning anything on there. You are merely asking the user to turn them on for you. iOS then responds to that by turning on the permissions. Your app doesn't go anywhere near writing the actual permissions.

Comment: @Sean - Thxs for you comment. That is exactly how I do it right now. But it would been nice if there would be a way to disallow local notifications.